# Inline function always returns the same value

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement my own priority queue that does the same thing as the standard priority queue from STL. The elements from queue have to respect an order, and for this I used a compare function. For this case the elements from queue are sorted ascending by their frequency and the compare function returns the difference between 2 elements' frequency. If the difference is less than 0, we found the place where the element should be inserted, otherwise the iteration continues.

My struggle is that the compare function always returns the value 0 regardless of difference between frequences (eg if one element has frequency equals to 2 and other has it equals to 3, their difference if -1, but relation function will return 0).

Here is the source code:

```
#pragma once
#include"BinaryTree.h"
typedef int(*TRelation)(const BinaryTree& bt1, const BinaryTree& bt2);


inline int getPriority(const BinaryTree& bt1, const BinaryTree& bt2) {
    return bt1.getFrequence() - bt2.getFrequence();
 }


class PriorityQueue {

TRelation relation;
BinaryTree* first;


public:

PriorityQueue() {
    relation = getPriority;
    first = nullptr;
}

void add(BinaryTree* e) {

    if (first == nullptr) {
        first = e;
        return;
    }
    //add at start
    if (relation(*e, *first)<0)
    {
        BinaryTree *aux= first;
        first = e;
        e->next = aux;
        return;
    }
    BinaryTree *pre=first ;
    BinaryTree *current = first;
    while (current!=nullptr && relation(*e, *current)>=0) {
        pre = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    pre->next = e;
    e->next = current;
}
```

I also tried different implementation of getPriority() function like changing its returning type, elements' type, etc.

Comment: You are saying that `bt1.getFrequence() - bt2.getFrequence()` is always `0`?  We would probably need to see that function to explain why that is.

Comment: The problem is not with getFrequence() function because the returned value is correct.                                                              ` ` ` 
          `class PriorityQueue;
           class BinaryTree {
         Node* root;
         BinaryTree* next;
         int frequence;
         friend class PriorityQueue; 
          public:

          BinaryTree(const TElement& e, int frq) {
  root = new Node(e);
  frequence = frq;
  next = nullptr;
 }

 const TFrequence& getFrequence() const{
  return frequence;
 }

     };`

Comment: A larger question: Are you trying to implement a heap in that binary tree, or are you just building a binary search tree to serve as a priority queue? I'll tell you right away that it's much easier to implement a binary heap in an array or vector than it is to implement in a binary tree. If you're determined to implement a node-based heap, consider a [Paring Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), which is easier to implement and will perform better.